# Al tratar de insertar datos en la DB me da error [HY093]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

El caso es que estoy tratando de insertar usuarios mediante PDO y CRUD y me esta generando un error el cual no consigo solucionar.

El error es exactamente este

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Archivo que contiene el formulario alta_usuarios.php:

```
<form action="administrar_usuario.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
<input type="text" name="dni" placeholder="DNI">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
<input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo">
<input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion">
<input type="text" name="cod_postal" placeholder="Codigo Postal">
<input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Teléfono">
<input type="text" name="fecha_nac" placeholder="Fecha nacimiento">
<input type="text" name="foto" placeholder="foto">
<input type="text" name="curso" placeholder="curso">
<input type='hidden' name='insertar' value='insertar'>
<!--Con esto ejecutamos la funcion de insertar-->

<select name="tipo">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Administración</option>
    <option value="3">Alumno</option>
    <option value="4">Profesor</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="altaUsuario" value="Crear">
```

Controlador administrar_usuario.php:

```
    <?php 
include_once('crud_usuario.php');
include_once('class_usuarios.php');

$crud = new CrudUsuario();
$usuario = new Usuario();

if (isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
    $usuario->setIdUsuario(NULL);
    $usuario->setDni($_POST['dni']);
    $usuario->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
    $usuario->setApellido($_POST['apellido']);
    $usuario->setContrasena($_POST['contrasena']);
    $usuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $usuario->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);
    $usuario->setDireccion($_POST['direccion']);
    $usuario->setCodPostal($_POST['cod_postal']);
    $usuario->setTel($_POST['tel']);
    $usuario->setFechaNac($_POST['fecha_nac']);
    $usuario->setFoto($_POST['foto']);
    $usuario->setCurso($_POST['curso']);
    $usuario->setTipo($_POST['tipo']);
    $crud->insertar($usuario);
}

?>
```

Archivo que contiene el crud, crud_usuario.php:

```
    <?php 
require_once('conexion.php');

class CrudUsuario{
    //constructor de la clase
    public function __contruct(){}

    public function insertar($usuario){
            $db=BaseDatos::conectar();

            try {
                $insert=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO Usuarios values(NULL,:dni,:nombre,:apellido,:contrasena,:email,:usuario,:direccion,:cod_postal,:telefono,:fecha_nac,:foto,:curso,:estado,:tipo)');
                $insert->bindValue('id_usuario',$usuario->getIdUsuario());
                $insert->bindValue('nombre',$usuario->getNombre());
                $insert->bindValue('apellido',$usuario->getApellido());
                $insert->bindValue('contrasena',$usuario->getContrasena());
                $insert->bindValue('email',$usuario->getEmail());
                $insert->bindValue('usuario',$usuario->getUsuario());
                $insert->bindValue('direccion',$usuario->getDireccion());
                $insert->bindValue('cod_postal',$usuario->getCodPostal());
                $insert->bindValue('telefono',$usuario->getTel());
                $insert->bindValue('fecha_nac',$usuario->getFechaNac());
                $insert->bindValue('foto',$usuario->getFoto());
                $insert->bindValue('curso',$usuario->getCurso());
                $insert->bindValue('estado',$usuario->getEstado());
                $insert->bindValue('tipo',$usuario->getTipo());
                $insert->execute(); 
            }   
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                print $e->getMessage ();
            }

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: prueba a poner un "print_r($insert); die()" antes del execute, para ver si podemos ver como esta compuesta la sql y ver si hay algun parametro que falta. Aparentemente es cosa de que uno de los campos es numerico y no le pasas nada, pero hay que ver la consulta como queda...

Comment: Me genera esto, PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO Usuarios values(NULL,:dni,:nombre,:apellido,:contrasena,:email,:usuario,:direccion,:cod_postal,:telefono,:fecha_nac,:foto,:curso,:estado,:tipo) ) error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos errores en el código, uno al preparar la consulta SQL entre los datos que estás recibiendo, los que introduces en la consulta SQL y los que asignas con `bindValue` y el otro al asignar las variables, estás olvidando los dos puntos (poner `:dni` en vez de `dni` en las llamadas a `bindValue`).

Estás poniendo `id_usuario` en vez de `dni` en `$insert->bindValue('id_usuario',$usuario->getIdUsuario());`. Al hacerlo mal estás provocando el error que te sale, que el parámetro `id_usuario` no está definido en la consulta preparada.

Imagino que, por los datos que das de entrada y el SQL, lo que quieres es asociar el valor `dni` y obtenerlo a través de `$usuario->getDni()`.

Prueba:

```
try {
    $insert=$db->prepare('
      INSERT INTO Usuarios
      VALUES (
        NULL,
        :dni,
        :nombre,
        :apellido,
        :contrasena,
        :email,
        :usuario,
        :direccion,
        :cod_postal,
        :telefono,
        :fecha_nac,
        :foto,
        :curso,
        :estado,
        :tipo
      )
    ');
    $insert->bindValue(':dni', $usuario->getDni());
    $insert->bindValue(':nombre', $usuario->getNombre());
    $insert->bindValue(':apellido', $usuario->getApellido());
    $insert->bindValue(':contrasena', $usuario->getContrasena());
    $insert->bindValue(':email', $usuario->getEmail());
    $insert->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario->getUsuario());
    $insert->bindValue(':direccion', $usuario->getDireccion());
    $insert->bindValue(':cod_postal', $usuario->getCodPostal());
    $insert->bindValue(':telefono', $usuario->getTel());
    $insert->bindValue(':fecha_nac', $usuario->getFechaNac());
    $insert->bindValue(':foto', $usuario->getFoto());
    $insert->bindValue(':curso', $usuario->getCurso());
    $insert->bindValue(':estado', $usuario->getEstado());
    $insert->bindValue(':tipo', $usuario->getTipo());
    $insert->execute(); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

O bien, yo preferiría:

```
try {
    $insert=$db->prepare('
      INSERT INTO Usuarios
      VALUES (
        :id_usuario,
        :dni,
        :nombre,
        :apellido,
        :contrasena,
        :email,
        :usuario,
        :direccion,
        :cod_postal,
        :telefono,
        :fecha_nac,
        :foto,
        :curso,
        :estado,
        :tipo
      )
    ');
    $insert->bindValue(':id_usuario', $usuario->getIdUsuario());
    $insert->bindValue(':dni', $usuario->getDni());
    $insert->bindValue(':nombre', $usuario->getNombre());
    $insert->bindValue(':apellido', $usuario->getApellido());
    $insert->bindValue(':contrasena', $usuario->getContrasena());
    $insert->bindValue(':email', $usuario->getEmail());
    $insert->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario->getUsuario());
    $insert->bindValue(':direccion', $usuario->getDireccion());
    $insert->bindValue(':cod_postal', $usuario->getCodPostal());
    $insert->bindValue(':telefono', $usuario->getTel());
    $insert->bindValue(':fecha_nac', $usuario->getFechaNac());
    $insert->bindValue(':foto', $usuario->getFoto());
    $insert->bindValue(':curso', $usuario->getCurso());
    $insert->bindValue(':estado', $usuario->getEstado());
    $insert->bindValue(':tipo', $usuario->getTipo());
    $insert->execute(); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Gracias fue eso, gracias por su atención!

Comment: De nada, y recuerda poner los dos puntos en los `bindValue`.